# Handler and thread/runnable

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

Can someone tell me why this doesn't work? I am trying to figure out how to use thread/runnable. Thread doesnt do much but just to loop and let the main thread know to update the text. I dont know what I missed, the centertext doesnt update. Thanks so much.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView centerText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final SysTimeObj sysTimeObj = new SysTimeObj();
        centerText = findViewById(R.id.centerText);
        Handler stHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) {
                super.handleMessage(msg);
                centerText.setText("thread updated");
            }
        };

        startThread(sysTimeObj, stHandler);
    }

    public void startThread(SysTimeObj sysTimeObj, Handler handler){
        clockThread rc = new clockThread(sysTimeObj, handler);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(rc);
        t1.start();

    }
}

public class clockThread implements Runnable {
    //private String sysTime;
    private Handler handler;
    SysTimeObj sysTimeObj;

    public clockThread(SysTimeObj sysTimeObj, Handler mHandler){
        //sysTime = GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime().toString();
        this.sysTimeObj = sysTimeObj;
        handler = mHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        sysTimeObj.setTime();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something on the *Main/UI Thread* after a certain amount of time ? On Android, you don't need a new thread for that.

The *Main Thread* has a message queue that you can *Post* to. That message queue is emptied on a regular basis. Posted messages can be configured to be executed at a later time (which is what you seem to want).

To post messages, you need to create a `Handler` for the target thread. This `Handler` will let you send messages to that thread. Then, *Post* a `Runnable` to that thread using one of the posting methods availlable (here, `postDelayed`).

You'll end with something like this :

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView yourTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        yourTextView = findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);

        Handler handler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                yourTextView.setText("Updated after 100 ms");
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

If threads is really what you want, I suggest you look at [AsyncTasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads#AsyncTask). You might also want to look at the official documentation about [Process and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads) on Android Developpers.